# jQuery plugin, just pass values back, no need for element to run on

Tags: jquery

This may be easier to give an example, i'm making a jQuery plugin, i don't want the user to pick an element to run the plugin on, just to pass it data. ie:

```
$('body').myPlugin({'value' : 'hey'}); //just want to pass it values, 'body' is irrelevant
```

How can i go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [`extend`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/) method:

```
$.extend({
    myPlugin: function(someArg) {
        //Do stuff
    }
});
```

When only one argument is supplied to `extend`, the object to be extended is assumed to be jQuery itself. You can then access your function as follows:

```
$.myPlugin({'value' : 'hey'});
```

Comment: If you write your plugin as shown in the first code snippet, users can use the second snippet. Or have I understood what you're trying to do completely wrong?

Comment: Hmmm, i'm ok with the plugin side of things, it's just when the user would normally put $('.elementToRunOn').myPlugin(); the elementtorunon is irrelevant for my plugin...

Comment: Yeah, so change the way you've written your plugin (I'm assuming you've done the normal `$.fn.myPlugin = function`) to use the `extend` method instead, and then users of your plugin can call it as shown, without the need to select an element.